# Google Map Fragment causing Fatal signal 11

Tags: android

I have an activity containing a fragment called infoViewFragment that contains a Google Map and another fragment called profileViewFragment.

I want to switch activities, but when I call startActivity() and finish() within the old activity, I receive a fatal signal 11.

I've narrowed it down to the Google Maps fragment being the root cause of the issue since I only receive the fatal signal once getMap() is called and thus the map view is initialized, but I am at a loss as to how to handle the problem.

Here's my LogCat:

```
06-04 06:17:35.918: D/dalvikvm(11504): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-04 06:17:36.028: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 6% free 2997K/3180K, paused 0ms, total 3ms
06-04 06:17:36.028: I/dalvikvm-heap(11504): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.415MB for 10886412-byte allocation
06-04 06:17:36.068: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 2% free 13626K/13812K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
06-04 06:17:36.148: D/(11504): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7d55cf0, tid 11504
06-04 06:17:36.178: W/EGL_emulation(11504): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 06:17:36.178: D/OpenGLRenderer(11504): Enabling debug mode 0
06-04 06:17:41.138: D/DEBUG(11504): 00000000-40c0-4ae1-ffff-ffff99d603a9
06-04 06:17:41.138: D/DEBUG(11504): performLogin() Passing: Guest
06-04 06:17:41.188: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 150K, 2% free 15496K/15772K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
06-04 06:17:41.198: W/Restarun(11504): GPS coordinates not found!
06-04 06:17:41.198: W/Restarun(11504): Falling back to predefined coordinates
06-04 06:17:41.719: I/u(11504): Making Creator dynamically
06-04 06:17:41.719: I/Google Maps Android API(11504): Google Play services client version: 4452000
06-04 06:17:41.719: I/Google Maps Android API(11504): Google Play services package version: 4452036
06-04 06:17:41.749: I/fpp(11504): Making Creator dynamically
06-04 06:17:41.749: I/Google Maps Android API(11504): Google Play services client version: 4452000
06-04 06:17:41.779: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1543K, 10% free 16002K/17656K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
06-04 06:17:41.779: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 15K, 9% free 16106K/17656K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-04 06:17:41.779: I/dalvikvm-heap(11504): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.910MB for 1127532-byte allocation
06-04 06:17:41.789: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 9% free 17207K/18760K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-04 06:17:41.879: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 436K, 7% free 17575K/18760K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
06-04 06:17:41.879: I/dalvikvm-heap(11504): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.393MB for 3276812-byte allocation
06-04 06:17:41.899: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 20772K/21964K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
06-04 06:17:42.809: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1018K, 5% free 21802K/22932K, paused 3ms, total 6ms
06-04 06:17:43.159: W/EGL_emulation(11504): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 06:17:43.159: I/Choreographer(11504): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-04 06:17:48.199: D/(11504): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb81a7360, tid 11536
06-04 06:17:48.249: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4535K, 20% free 19294K/23944K, paused 5ms, total 7ms
06-04 06:17:48.579: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1408K, 17% free 19889K/23944K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
06-04 06:17:48.779: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1903K, 17% free 20033K/23944K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-04 06:17:49.159: D/dalvikvm(11504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2006K, 17% free 20075K/23944K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-04 06:17:53.509: D/DEBUG(11504): Performing logout
06-04 06:17:53.579: W/EGL_emulation(11504): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-04 06:17:53.969: A/libc(11504): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000002 (code=1), thread 11536 (Thread-399)
```

And relevant code:

```
public void doLogout(View view) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.remove( viewInfoFragment );
    transaction.remove( profileInfoFragment );
    transaction.commit();

    Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean( "logout", true );
    intent.putExtras( args );
    startActivity( intent );
    this.finish();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_search );

    /* Retrieve the login information from the previous activity */
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    mUser.m_name = b.getString( "user_name" );
    mUser.m_fbPhoto = b.getString( "FB_photo" );
    mUser.beenPlaces = new ArrayList<Place>();
    mUser.favoritedPlaces = new ArrayList<Place>();

    /* Preload all layout fragments */
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    transaction.add( R.id.container, viewInfoFragment );
    transaction.add( R.id.container, profileInfoFragment );
    transaction.hide( viewInfoFragment );
    transaction.hide( profileInfoFragment );
    transaction.commit();

    /* Find the user's current location */
    Location m_location = new ServiceGPS( this ).getLocation();

    /* Attempt to pass phone's GPS latitude and longitude */
    try {
        mPlaces = new YelpAPI().execute( m_location.getLatitude(),
                m_location.getLongitude() ).get();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        /* Default to pre-set coordinates in case GPS fails */
        try {
            Log.w( "Restarun",
                    "GPS coordinates not found!\nFalling back to predefined coordinates" );
            mPlaces = new YelpAPI().execute( 32.8762142, -117.2354577 )
                    .get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /* Select a random restaurant in the list and move it to first position */
    Random rand = new Random();
    int pos = rand.nextInt( mPlaces.size() );
    Collections.swap( mPlaces, 0, pos );

    /* Load the list view */
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.pager );
    mPager.setAdapter( new MyAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager() ) );
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit( mPlaces.size() );
}

public void setMap(String m_name, String m_address) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder( this );
    Address location = null;

    try {

        List<Address> addressList;
        addressList = coder.getFromLocationName( m_address, 5 );
        if ( addressList != null ) {

            location = addressList.get( 0 );

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if ( location != null ) {
        LatLng Restaurant = new LatLng( location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude() );
        mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById( R.id.map )).getMap();
        if ( mGoogleMap != null ) {
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    Restaurant, 15 ) );

            mGoogleMap.clear();

            mGoogleMap.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng( location.getLatitude(), location
                                    .getLongitude() ) ).title( m_name ) )
                    .showInfoWindow();

        }
    }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fraginfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_addr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Address" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="eatHere"
            android:text="Eat Here" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:onClick="addFavorite"
            android:text="Add to Favorites" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post you all logcat .

Comment: I've posted my LogCat output as per requested.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment... but I have the same issue.  However, it only occurs on the haxm based emulator.  On a real device there has been no issue so far.  I'm tempted to believe its a bug in the emulator... but that's a scary assumption to make before shipping a product.

Comment: Actually, it does appear on certain devices. I forget which specific phone we used for development purposes since it was awhile ago, but it certainly does appear on hardware and definitely crashes the device.

I was unable to find the issue and had to use the Google Maps API to download an image. Multiple workarounds worked to some degree, but nothing completely fixed the issue.

Comment: My ultimate solution (workaround) was to use the support library and use the SupportMapFragment.  No problems now... but the original issue still bugs me.  I'm glad you mentioned that it CAN happen on real HW also -- that validates my decision to remove that activity and convert it to a fragment.

Comment: I'm getting this on a Sony Xperia running 4.4.2 - very annoying.